# Duvida sobre melhores praticas para API Rest (objeto -> json)

Tags: javascript, java, rest, restful

Tenho dúvidas com relação as melhoras praticas na conversão de json/objeto entre servidor (api rest) e cliente (framework javascript). Minha dúvida está é em relação aos objetos referenciados pela entidade principal, devo enviar apenas IDs ou objeto completo? Como exemplo (simples) tenho o seguinte relacionamento:

```
{
    "id":2,
    "nome":"SÃO GONÇALO",
    "cep":"24030103",
    "estado":{
                "id":1,
                "nome":"RIO DE JANEIRO",
                "sigla":"RJ"
            }
}
```

Essa estrutura representa o relacionamento entre CIDADE e ESTADO. Ao cadastrar uma nova cidade (POST) devo enviar o objeto “estado” completo ou apenas seu ID para o servidor? Exemplo:

- Enviando objeto “estado” completo (POST):

```
     {
            "nome":"SÃO GONÇALO",
            "cep":"24030103",
            "estado":{
                        "id":1,
                        "nome":"RIO DE JANEIRO",
                        "sigla":"RJ"
                    }
     }
```

- Enviando apenas ID do estado (POST):

```
    {
        "nome":"SÃO GONÇALO",
        "cep":"24030103",
        "idEstado": 1
     }
```

Qual dessas abordagens deve ser seguida?

Com relação a consultas (GET), devo retornar à referência completa do estado ou apenas seu ID? A abordagem de retornar apenas o ID tem o "problema" de necessitar de uma nova consulta (javascript) para conseguir exibir ao usuário o nome do estado.

Acredito que passar apenas o ID no POST seja o melhor, não trafega dados desnecessários. Caso o melhor seja seguir a linha do ID, qual a melhor pratica para converter esses IDs no servidor para objetos (preciso do objeto completo no servidor para validar negócio antes de persistir)?

Esse foi um exemplo simples, tenho modelos em meu negócio onde a quantidade de referências é bem grande. Trabalho com java no servidor e angular no frontend.

Comment: Normalmente é só o ID para redução de tráfego de dados... tanto que quando se tem tabelas somente o ID fica nelas

Answer (score -1):

Com relação ao `POST`, o maior problema quando se envia o objeto completo é a consistência de dados. Se por exemplo, por algum motivo, o estado vier com a seguinte estrutura:

```
 "estado":{
      "id":1,
      "nome": "SÃO PAULO",
      "sigla": "RJ"
  }
```

o que fazer?

Não sabemos se o frontend cometeu algum erro ao montar a requisição, ou se alguém alterou o request "no braço". Também tem a questão de dados redundantes, já que só com o `ID` você consegue buscar a referência completa do objeto.

Já quando falamos de um `GET`, a história se inverte. Como você mesmo mencionou, se trafegarmos somente o `ID`, será necessário outra requisição para buscar as informações do estado.

> Caso o melhor seja seguir a linha do ID, qual a melhor pratica para converter esses IDs no servidor para objetos ?

Realizar uma consulta que retorna o objeto completo, buscando pelo `ID`. Aí sim, aplicar as regras de negócio.

Comment: Obrigado. Seria interessante usar DTOs para cada entidade? Meu DTO teria os Ids das referencias e criaria conversores de DTO para entidade, onde esses conversores fariam o carregamento do objeto completo. Pesquisando vi uma abordagem onde a entidade (@Entity) tinha dois atributos (@Column) para o mesmo campo no banco de dados, um do tipo Integer (esse é persistido) e outro Objeto (esse é somente leitura), pelo que percebi o objetivo foi não criar DTOs e conversores.. particularmente não gostei da abordagem.

Comment: @Welmau, em geral tente não usar as entidades para representar seu Json, deixe elas com a responsabilidade de representar as tabelas do banco de dados e nada mais. O ideal é como disse, criar um `DTO` para representar cada entidade e alimentar ele com as informações da entidade, no request e response. Assim você terá flexibilidade e menos problemas para manter este código, evitando este tipo de solução que você mesmo mencionou.